# How can I package and run a binary with a jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins, plugins

I’m writing a jenkins plugin that’s dependent on a shell script binary to function. For project-specific reasons, I’m unable to download the binary dependency at runtime and it must be included and run from inside the plugin. Currently, I have the binary at the top level directory of my project but I’m unable to run it after the plugin is packaged into a .hpi file and loaded into Jenkins.

What would be the best way to accomplish this? Right now I’m testing the plugin via the .hpi file but it will be available on the marketplace.